# Initialize "final" variables in Scala

Tags: scala, initialization, final

Consider the following Java class:

```
public class C {
  private int n;
  private final int x;
  private final int y;
  public C(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    if (n < 0) {
      x = -1;
      y = -1;
    } else {
      x = 1;
      y = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

The `x,y` depend on `n`, after they are set they cannot be changed. How can this be accomplished in Scala? A `private val x` is final, but since it is `val` it cannot be changed in the "constructor". A `private var x` is private, but not final, so that although it's not visible to users, it is visible to a programmer who might mistakenly modify it.

In the case of a single "final" variable, one could do as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376019/4743466), but if there are two (or more, as in what I'm actually coding), then I'm not sure how to do it. Here's one way:

```
class C(n: Int) {
  private val x = if (n < 0) -1 else 1
  private val y = if (n < 0) -1 else 1 // code duplication
}
```

Here's another way:

```
class C(n: Int) {
  private val (x,y) = if (n < 0) (-1,-1) else (1,1)
}
```

I can work with the latter, but it feels roundabout and generally ugly, so I'm wondering if there is some other way? Another downside to the above is that I can't use all-caps names, which I'd like to do (even though that's possibly counter to Scala style).

Thanks!

Comment: Can't use all-caps? Why not?

Comment: @jwvh Compiler says value not found, try: `echo "class C(n: Int) { private val (Abc, Xyz) = if (n < 0) (-1,-1) else (1,1) }" | scala`

Comment: The syntax you want is `val (A @ _, B @ _) = ???`

Comment: @som-snytt Can you expand on that? I don't know how to use that.

Comment: To introduce a name starting with uppercase in a pattern, use the @ syntax to bind the name. Instead of `val (X, Y) = someTuple`, `val (X @ _, Y @ _)`, where underscore is a pattern. Similarly `val P(X @ _)` for an extractor P.

Answer (score 5):

```
// make the constructor private to avoid setting x,y directly
case class C private(n: Int, x: Int, y: Int) 

// have a "smart constructor" in the companion object
// that implements your rule
object C {
  def apply(n: Int): C = if (n < 0) C(n, -1,-1) else C(n, 1, 1)
}

// create an instance like this
C(1)
```

Or, don't store `x` and `y` at all, just compute them when needed

```
case class C(n: Int){
   def x: Int = if (n < 0) -1 else 1  
      // could also make it a lazy-val if expensive
   def y: Int = x   // code re-use if the logic is really the same
}
```

Comment: "if the logic is really the same" it's not, it was an example. Anyway I'll have a look at companion object constructor, thanks.

Comment: @Thilo, Great answer but still `C(1).copy(x = 5) ` is possible

Comment: @ZviMints. Ah, yes, that's true. Scala 3 fixes this. For Scala 2, you have to add some extra boiler-plate (or maybe give up on the case class and make it a normal class).

Comment: @ZviMints: From Scala 2.13.2 onwards, you can set the `-Xsource:3` compiler option, and then the automatic `copy` and `apply` methods will have the same modifier as the constructor.   https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7702 (read about that at https://tuleism.github.io/blog/2020/scala-smart-constructors/ )

Comment: @Thilo I looked into it now, but it's not gonna be feasible, or rather, it's not gonna look "better" than say `class C ... private val (x,y, /* a bunch of final vars */) = init()`. As for `case`, I don't know what that would add, I've mostly seen that for pattern matching, and my class isn't well-suited for that. As for "don't store .. at all", there was a reason to pre-compute and store them in the first place so I need to keep that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what's "ugly" about your solution, seems fine to me.
If you want to use caps, the simple way is to split them into two:

```
   val Abs = if (n < 0) -1 else 1
   val Xyz = if (n < 0) -1 else 1
```

re. "code duplication": if you for some reason want to have two variables that have the same value, you are going to have to duplicate code that sets it one way or another. It's not a syntax problem, it's a problem with your design.
This:

```
      x = -1;
      y = -1;
```

Is actually also duplicating code.
If you are so set on avoiding the visibility of code duplication, you can always write `val Xyz = Abc` if you think that helps anything.

Comment: It's ugly because it introduces an extra field, javap says private final scala.Tuple2 x$1;

Comment: My actual fields don't have the same value, what I posted was just a brief example.

Comment: @som-snytt I have no idea what you mean. Who cares what javap says?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund if they don't have the same value, then I don't know what is the "code duplication" you are talking about.

Comment: @Dima Like this: `private val x = if (n < 0) a else b; private val y = if (n < 0) c else d`, the condition is the same but occurs in two places.

Comment: To clarify, in a class, the convenient syntax `val (x, y) = z` has the inconvenience of introducing a "dummy" field to the class. Maybe you don't care about that, or maybe it matters. It certainly is not pretty.

Comment: @som-snytt well, in the same vein declaring a `val foo` "has the inconvenience" of introducing a "dummy" field `foo` (or a dummy function `foo` if you prefer). Also, declaring a default value for a function parameter creates a "dummy" method. If these don't irritate you, I don't know why the tuple thing does. It's just an implementation detail, that is inconsequential to the downstream code.

Comment: Some people care about the size of their objects. If I implement the following, it will be an option you can disable. https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8699#issuecomment-586162164

Comment: Those people should be using java ... or better yet "C", if they care so much :)